# compilation error when using std::unique_ptr as value in tbb::concurrent_hash_map

Tags: gcc, c++11, clang, unique-ptr, tbb

I'm trying to replace a `std::unordered_map` with a `tbb::concurrent_hash_map`.

My original code:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<V> V_ptr;

std::unordered_map<K, V_ptr> hm;
V_ptr v (new V);
K k;

hm.insert (std::make_pair (k, std::move (v)));
```

compiles fine with clang 3.3.  Switching the unordered_map to a concurrent_hash_map:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<V> V_ptr;

tbb::concurrent_hash_map<K, V_ptr> hm;
V_ptr v (new V);
K k;

hm.insert (std::make_pair (k, std::move (v)));
```

results in the error: `...stl_pair.h:105:21: error: call to deleted constructor of
      'std::unique_ptr<...`

Is this a bug in clang 3.3?  I remember there being similar errors in gcc 4.5 when using std::unique_ptrs in many containers.  (The above original code will not compile with gcc 4.5 for ex.)  Or maybe I missed something about concurrent_hash_maps?

Comment: Sounds like tbb::concurrent_hash_map may require copy constructible / copy assignable rather than only move constructible / move assignable types.

Comment: @mattnewport Yeah you're right - right in the docs  [link](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls.htm) - must've missed it "Types Key and T must model the CopyConstructible concept" - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation [`tbb::concurrent_hash_map`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls.htm) takes argument only via `const&` which triggers copy of `unique_ptr`:

```
bool insert( const value_type& value );
```

As workaround you may use `std::shared_ptr` or store `unique_ptr`s in stand-alone vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<V>> ptrs;
```

and store raw pointers in `concurrent_hash_map`. Though, that may be not acceptable for your use cases (like frequent deletions).

Another possibility is to use `std::auto_ptr` or something similar. But that is dangerous - right copy should arrive into bucket, so you have to test it.

Comment: maybe tbb will change and allow `bool insert( value_type&& value );` anybody know?

Comment: @scmcduffee I think they will update to C++11 eventually. By the way, looks like [`concurrent_unordered_map::insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755843%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) of `Microsot PPL` supports rvalue references.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can work around this limitation by using a more complex form of insertion into tbb::concurrent_hash_map. The following code snippet is not tested, but a priori I see no reason why it would not work:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<V> V_ptr;

tbb::concurrent_hash_map<K, V_ptr> hm;
V_ptr v (new V);
K k;
{ // this scope controls lifetime of the accessor
    tbb::concurrent_hash_map::accessor a;
    hm.insert (a, k);          // insert or find the key
    a->second = std::move(v);  // assign the value
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the answer to my question is that tbb does not support std::move yet.  I'm going to stick with shared_ptr for now but the following work around does work:

```
struct V_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<V> {

    typedef std::unique_ptr<V> uvptr;
    using uvptr::uvptr;
    V_ptr () : std::unique_ptr<V> () {};

    V_ptr (const V_ptr& rhs) {
        this->swap (const_cast<V_ptr&> (rhs));
    }
};
```

Though I'm hesitant to recommend it.