# NDK C++11, call to deleted constructor error

Tags: gcc, c++11, android-ndk, clang

I have a class called RenderCommand:

```
class RenderCommand
{
public:
    RenderCommandType commandType;

    RenderCommand() : commandType(RenderCommandTypeNone) {};
    virtual ~RenderCommand() {};
};
```

I then have a queue of these RenderCommands which stores unique_ptrs to them:

```
typedef std::deque<std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>> RenderQueue;
```

Finally in a section of code, I create a vector of these RenderQueues, and try to resize it:

```
std::vector<RenderQueue> queues;
queues.resize(4);
```

The resize line is giving me a few issues. In clang I get the error message:

```
call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand, std::default_delete<RenderCommand> >'
```

With GCC 4.8, I just get a whole bunch of errors similar to

```
required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>, const std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>&, const std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>, std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>&, std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>*>; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>]'
```

**This compiles fine in Visual Studio 2012** however so I'm a little lost. I appreciate any help you guys can give!

**EDIT:** RenderCommandType is just an enum:

```
enum RenderCommandType
{
    RenderCommandTypeNone = 0,
    RenderCommandTypeBeginRepeat,
    RenderCommandTypeEndRepeat,
    RenderCommandTypeBeginScene,
    RenderCommandTypeEndScene,
    //etc
};
```

**EDIT2:** Ok this seems to be a std::deque problem, changing RenderQueue to:

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<RenderCommand>> RenderQueue;
```

works. Also removing references to my own class and just using an int still doesn't work (unless like above I replace deque with vector):

```
std::vector<std::deque<std::unique_ptr<int>>> tempQueue;
tempQueue.resize(4);
```

:-/

Comment: Let me telepathically guess: RenderCommandType have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors, or not trivially copyable? Please add RenderCommandType definition to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, RenderCommandType is just an enum, added it to the original question.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/19692951/1741542

Comment: Thanks, I saw that before but thought that it's not completely relevant since they were trying to use TBB, whereas I'm trying to use standard containers. Does this mean that std::deque in the NDK doesn't support std::move yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your example to

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

void f()
{
    std::vector<std::deque<A> > q;
    q.resize(4);
}
```

With g++ 4.6, this example compiles fine. From g++ 4.7 on however, it prints a lot of error messages, finally resulting in the mentioned

```
error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
```

Replacing `deque` with `vector` or `list` doesn't show this behaviour.

So, it seems this is either a regression from g++ 4.6 to 4.7 or a correction of a previous bug. In any case, I filed a bug report with g++, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59192

Comment: Thank you for testing! I also submitted a bug report, but (probably incorrectly) to Android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62479

Comment: Well, lets see what they make out of this. They should either acknowledge and fix it or be able to explain, why this is correct behaviour.